# How Do You Have Objects Stay In Front Of The Camera While It's Moving?

Tags: camera

In other words, if you set keyframes for the camera, then between the keyframes it's difficult to determine where to (for example) quickly put text in front of the camera while it's moving.  Is there any way to set objects so they are positioned in front of the camera automatically as it moves?  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

You can *Parent* an object to the camera by first selecting the object, then the camera (so that the camera is highlighted in yellow), then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>*> Object*:

[image]

The object will now stay fixed relative to the camera:

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that there were a few things done to achieve the full effect in the animated GIF (namely having the cube copy the camera's rotation and moving it closer to the camera). To go from the still image to the GIF is not as simple just pressing Ctrl+P.

Comment: That said, I laughed when I watched the cube and camera wiggle across my screen. I'm not sure why, but it's funny.